# How can I reset/revert a string back to its orginal form after mutating it

Tags: python

Alright, so I want to reset a word after I have to change/mutated it without the reset method taking any parameters. Reset() should revert the text after the use() method is used. Is there any way of doing this?

```
Class words

def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        
    def use(self): # sets the text as an empty string
        self.text = ""

    def reset(self): # revert empty string back to the original text
```

Here is the unit test for reset()

```
import unittest
from word import word

def test_reset(self):
        string = word("Sunshine")
        string.use()
        string.reset()
        self.assertEqual("Sunshine", string.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be way out of line but... why don't you just copy it?

```py
Class words

def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.original = text
        
    def use(self): # sets the text as an empty string
        self.text = ""

    def reset(self): # revert empty string back to the original text
        self.text = self.original
```

Comment: wow it worked thanks, guess I was just overthinking this

Comment: No probel, please mark as solved :)